How can I install the cryptography module on the latest python version (3.13)?
I need to install the cryptography module since it is a dependency for many modules in my python project that I want to migrate to Python 3.13.

I remember that the same problem occured, when I was migrating from
3.7 to 3.9, but sadly I cannot find the old solution.

It failes to build, even though I've installed the requirements from the cryptography docs:

sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python3-dev cargo pkg-config
Rust compiler
C compiler
updated pip

My system: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
I get this error message, when installing with python -m pip install cryptography:
python -m pip install cryptography
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting cryptography
  Using cached cryptography-42.0.5.tar.gz (671 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting cffi>=1.12 (from cryptography)
  Using cached cffi-1.16.0-cp313-cp313-linux_armv7l.whl
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography)
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/pycparser/pycparser-2.22-py3-none-any.whl (117 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: cryptography
  Building wheel for cryptography (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for cryptography (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [209 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-313
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-313/cryptography
      **....**
           Running `/tmp/pip-install-g1jvcxpi/cryptography_fed742100e7b483f8824b7115fe5ea08/src/rust/target/release/build/lock_api-04c76b29f0c26505/build-script-build`
         Compiling memoffset v0.9.0
           Running `/home/pi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/rustc --crate-name build_script_build /home/pi/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-1cd66030c949c28d/memoffset-0.9.0/build.rs --error-form
at=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C overflow-checks=on --cfg 'feature="default"' -C metadata=09c4f5391cced98d -
C extra-filename=-09c4f5391cced98d --out-dir /tmp/pip-install-g1jvcxpi/cryptography_fed742100e7b483f8824b7115fe5ea08/src/rust/target/release/build/memoffset-09c4f5391cced98d -C strip=debuginfo -L dependency=/tmp/pip-install-g1
jvcxpi/cryptography_fed742100e7b483f8824b7115fe5ea08/src/rust/target/release/deps --extern autocfg=/tmp/pip-install-g1jvcxpi/cryptography_fed742100e7b483f8824b7115fe5ea08/src/rust/target/release/deps/libautocfg-66f8aacc3220b665.rlib --cap-lints allow`
           Running `/tmp/pip-install-g1jvcxpi/cryptography_fed742100e7b483f8824b7115fe5ea08/src/rust/target/release/build/pyo3-ffi-986b831f7d0a90f7/build-script-build`
      error: failed to run custom build command for `pyo3-ffi v0.20.3`

      Caused by:
        process didn't exit successfully: `/tmp/pip-install-g1jvcxpi/cryptography_fed742100e7b483f8824b7115fe5ea08/src/rust/target/release/build/pyo3-ffi-986b831f7d0a90f7/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
        --- stdout
        cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PYO3_CROSS
        cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PYO3_CROSS_LIB_DIR
        cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PYO3_CROSS_PYTHON_VERSION
        cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PYO3_CROSS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION
        cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PYO3_PRINT_CONFIG
        cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PYO3_USE_ABI3_FORWARD_COMPATIBILITY

        --- stderr
        error: the configured Python interpreter version (3.13) is newer than PyO3's maximum supported version (3.12)
        = help: please check if an updated version of PyO3 is available. Current version: 0.20.3
        = help: set PYO3_USE_ABI3_FORWARD_COMPATIBILITY=1 to suppress this check and build anyway using the stable ABI
      warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
      error: `cargo rustc --lib --message-format=json-render-diagnostics --manifest-path src/rust/Cargo.toml --release -v --features pyo3/extension-module --crate-type cdylib --` failed with code 101
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cryptography, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects


To quote the error message: "error: the configured Python interpreter version (3.13) is newer than PyO3's maximum supported version (3.12)".
